# OpenCV matrix and FileNodeIterator: selecting the first iteration

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

What I'm trying to do is take the very first matrix from an iteration, and save it as a separate matrix that I can then use to perform functions on the rest of the data. Below is my code for the iterations;

```
FileNode n = fs.root();
    for (FileNodeIterator current = n.begin(); current != n.end(); current++) 
    {
        FileNode item = *current;
        Mat v, pose;
        item["pose"] >> v;
        string Frame;
        Frame = item.name();

        if (v.rows != 0) // finding the nodes that contain data and saving them as "pose"
        {
            transpose(v, pose);
            pose.size();
            cout << "The size of pose for " << Frame;
            cout << " is: \n" << pose.size()<< "\n Data was collected for this frame: \n" << pose << endl;
        }

        if (v.rows != 6) // Nodes with no data
        {
            cout << "The size of pose for " << Frame;
            cout << " is: \n" << v.size() << "\n No Data was collected for this frame. \n" << endl;

        }
```

Is there a way of taking the very first instance of "pose" and saving it as another matrix, for example, "base"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, maybe what you want is to declare a flag you can use to only save the first instance of your matrix, something like this:

```
FileNode n = fs.root();
bool firstTime = true;
Mat base;
for (FileNodeIterator current = n.begin(); current != n.end(); current++) 
{
    FileNode item = *current;
    Mat v, pose;
    item["pose"] >> v;
    string Frame;
    Frame = item.name();

    if (v.rows != 0) // finding the nodes that contain data and saving them as "pose"
    {
        transpose(v, pose);
        pose.size();
        cout << "The size of pose for " << Frame;
        cout << " is: \n" << pose.size()<< "\n Data was collected for this frame: \n" << pose << endl;
    }

    if (v.rows != 6) // Nodes with no data
    {
        cout << "The size of pose for " << Frame;
        cout << " is: \n" << v.size() << "\n No Data was collected for this frame. \n" << endl;

    }

    if(firstTime) 
    {
        base = pose.clone();
        firstTime = false;
    }
}
```

Note the `clone()`, this is needed if you want a full copy of the matrix header and data.